# Parametrizing a surface (Cylinder bounded by a plane)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, surface-integrals

I'm looking for a solution verification:

Let $S$ be the lateral surface of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ bounded below by the $xy$-plane and above by the plane $y+z = 2$.

Is this a correct parametrization for $S$: $r(\theta, z) = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta), z)$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $0 \leq z \leq 2 - \sin(\theta)$?

Then I would like to find $\iint_S F\cdot dS$ where $F(x, y, z) = [x, y, z]$ and the surface is oriented outwards.

So $r_\theta \times r_z = (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta, 0) \times(0, 0, 1)= (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0)$ which is already pointing outwards unless I'm wrong, so then $\iint_S F\cdot dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2-\sin(\theta)} (\cos \theta, \sin\theta, z) \cdot (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0)\,dzd\theta = \cdots = 4\pi$.

Comment: Well, if you are taking $\theta$ with the usual definition (angle from $x$ axis) as it seems, no. The cylinder lateral surface maximum height is on the $-y$ direction, meaning $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}$. Taking $\sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})$ should do.

Comment: Yes your working is all correct.